# Decoding special char from .rtf or .doc using php

Tags: special-characters, decoding, iso-8859-1, latin1

i am trying to find a clean way to decode some "special characters" using php, i have an RTF file (aslo PDF and DOC with sane kind of issue), i manage to open it and find clear text in it, put at the end it still output some character like : Ã© for é or Ã§ for ç. 
I have tried mb_detect_encoding (with "auto" also) but it detect "ACSII", i have try to convert using mb_convert_encoding($mytext,'ISO-8859-1'), mb_convert_encoding($mytext,'ISO-8859-15'),
mb_convert_encoding($mytext,'UTF-8') and then UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1, htmlspecialchars, utf8_decode (recursively). 
I made a mapping table but i don't think it the best way to do it ?

Xavier VILAIN

PS : Most of the document have been create in france latin charset.

Comment: What do you mean by "most of the document..." is the document in mixed charsets?